# How does codeigniter parse view file and repalce values of variable by passed values?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to read the source code and other resources but it is not clear to me. I am wondering how it parses the view file and replaces values of various variables by passed values.  I have similar requirement that needs to be developed using core php where I needs to parse a html file similar as codeigniter view file with variables ({variable_name}) and then needs to replace it values dynamically. I need to do it using core php so I can't use smarty or any other template script engine.

Comment: `parser.php` in libraries folder.... contains all your answers. It will be too long and broad to answer each step. So try to take a few steps and come when you are stuck at a particular position.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something to be able to send a template and variables, look into smarty templating

http://www.smarty.net/

It uses curly braces, which are more and more becoming common place, and quickly become easy to use, and easier for others to read in cases where you might be working on the PHP end of things, but then have a frontend designer who only ever touches the view files.

Some sample code from here: http://www.smarty.net/syntax_comparison

```
{foreach $foo as $bar}
  {if $bar@iteration is div by 4}
    </tr><tr>
  {/if}
  <td>{$bar}</td>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know about smarty but as I mentioned I need to do this thing in core php as I want to know how we can do same thing done by smarty or codeignitor using the core php i.e. parsing of html file with variables and replacing it with values. Thanks